# How to stop visual studio from producing the .application file

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I poked around some menus about publishing and now Visual Studio has started to output a .application file. I tried to ctrl+f "publish" in the .csproj, nevertheless Visual Studio still outputs this file. How can I stop this?

[image]

Comment: *Disclaimer: I have tried googling but the word ".Application file" but the word is too generic to be useful.

Comment: This is the answer. Thanks!